# No audio heard, yet Linux thinks played successfully

Tags: audio, pipewire, usb-audio, alsamixer

I had audio working on my AlmaLinux 9 installation, using a USB sound card.  I seemed to have changed something because I no longer hear audio (but AlmaLinux thinks its successfully playing a sound).  I did switch from GUI to text mode on boot, but I don't think that should matter.  I have no idea how to proceed...hopefully someone sees something wrong here:

For example, the following command completes successfully:

```
aplay /data/sounds/intruder_alert.wav
Playing WAVE '/data/sounds/intruder_alert.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 22050 Hz, Mono
```

I confirmed my USB audio device is detected on bootup (not sure if 'input,hidraw1' is a clue):

```
[    2.586749] hub 2-2:1.0: USB hub found
[    2.589077] hub 2-2:1.0: 7 ports detected
[    3.536316] usb 2-2.1: new full-speed USB device number 4 using uhci_hcd
[    4.432226] usb 2-2.1: New USB device found, idVendor=08bb, idProduct=2902, bcdDevice= 1.00
[    4.432236] usb 2-2.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    4.432243] usb 2-2.1: Product: USB Audio CODEC
[    4.432248] usb 2-2.1: Manufacturer: Burr-Brown from TI
[    4.524947] input: Burr-Brown from TI               USB Audio CODEC  as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2.1/2-2.1:1.3/0003:08BB:2902.0002/input/input6
[    4.583437] hid-generic 0003:08BB:2902.0002: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.00 Device [Burr-Brown from TI               USB Audio CODEC ] on usb-0000:02:00.0-2.1/input3
```

and sound related drivers are loaded by kernel:

```
 lsmod | grep snd
snd_seq_dummy          16384  0
snd_hrtimer            16384  1
snd_usb_audio         385024  2
snd_usbmidi_lib        45056  1 snd_usb_audio
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_usb_audio
snd_seq                94208  7 snd_seq_dummy
snd_pcm               151552  1 snd_usb_audio
snd_timer              49152  3 snd_seq,snd_hrtimer,snd_pcm
snd_rawmidi            45056  1 snd_usbmidi_lib
snd_seq_device         16384  2 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi
snd                   122880  14 snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hwdep,snd_usb_audio,snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
soundcore              16384  1 snd
mc                     69632  1 snd_usb_audio
```

Since I'm running pipewire and the nodes are

```
   pw-cli ls Node
        id 28, type PipeWire:Interface:Node/3
                object.serial = "28"
                factory.id = "10"
                priority.driver = "20000"
                node.name = "Dummy-Driver"
        id 29, type PipeWire:Interface:Node/3
                object.serial = "29"
                factory.id = "10"
                priority.driver = "19000"
                node.name = "Freewheel-Driver"
        id 31, type PipeWire:Interface:Node/3
                object.serial = "1736"
                object.path = "alsa:pcm:0:front:0:playback"
                factory.id = "18"
                client.id = "33"
                device.id = "44"
                priority.session = "1009"
                priority.driver = "1009"
                node.description = "PCM2902 Audio Codec Analog Stereo"
                node.name = "alsa_output.usb-Burr-Brown_from_TI_USB_Audio_CODEC-00.analog-stereo-output"
                node.nick = "USB Audio CODEC"
                media.class = "Audio/Sink"
        id 37, type PipeWire:Interface:Node/3
                object.serial = "35"
                factory.id = "10"
                client.id = "33"
                node.name = "Midi-Bridge"
                media.class = "Midi/Bridge"
        id 42, type PipeWire:Interface:Node/3
                object.serial = "1737"
                object.path = "alsa:pcm:0:hw:0:capture"
                factory.id = "18"
                client.id = "33"
                device.id = "44"
                priority.session = "2009"
                priority.driver = "2009"
                node.description = "PCM2902 Audio Codec Analog Stereo"
                node.name = "alsa_input.usb-Burr-Brown_from_TI_USB_Audio_CODEC-00.analog-stereo-input"
                node.nick = "USB Audio CODEC"
                media.class = "Audio/Source"
```

I also tried a simple speaker test:

```
speaker-test -c 2

speaker-test 1.2.8

Playback device is default
Stream parameters are 48000Hz, S16_LE, 2 channels
Using 16 octaves of pink noise
Rate set to 48000Hz (requested 48000Hz)
Buffer size range from 64 to 1048576
Period size range from 32 to 524288
Using max buffer size 1048576
Periods = 4
was set period_size = 262144
was set buffer_size = 1048576
 0 - Front Left
 1 - Front Right
Time per period = 11.005656
 0 - Front Left
^C 1 - Front Right
Time per period = 5.263193
```

And I checked the aplay devices

```
aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: CODEC [USB Audio CODEC], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

aplay -L
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
sysdefault
    Default Audio Device
oss
    Open Sound System
pipewire
    PipeWire Sound Server
default
    Default ALSA Output (currently PipeWire Media Server)
sysdefault:CARD=CODEC
    USB Audio CODEC, USB Audio
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=CODEC,DEV=0
    USB Audio CODEC, USB Audio
    Front output / input
surround21:CARD=CODEC,DEV=0
    USB Audio CODEC, USB Audio
    2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers
surround40:CARD=CODEC,DEV=0
    USB Audio CODEC, USB Audio
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=CODEC,DEV=0
    USB Audio CODEC, USB Audio
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=CODEC,DEV=0
    USB Audio CODEC, USB Audio
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=CODEC,DEV=0
    USB Audio CODEC, USB Audio
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=CODEC,DEV=0
    USB Audio CODEC, USB Audio
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
iec958:CARD=CODEC,DEV=0
    USB Audio CODEC, USB Audio
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
```

And alsa mixer says volume levels are up:

```
amixer
Simple mixer control 'Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 65536
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 55864 [85%] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 55864 [85%] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Capture',0
  Capabilities: cvolume cswitch cswitch-joined
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 65536
  Front Left: Capture 26213 [40%] [on]
  Front Right: Capture 26213 [40%] [on]
```

I've never seen this before and I'm not sure how to diagnose this.  Btw, I confirmed my speakers work fine (hear buzz when I touch the audio cable connections).

Comment: 1/ Please try **aplay -D hw:0,0** *blahblah* (explicitly defining the device) 2/ What about recording ? 3/ Change usb port.

Comment: I don't need recording nor have an availble source.  I tried the hw:0,0 device but same result.